# can the whole html of a page be sent to another domain with postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

just what the title says. can postMessage be used to send the whole content of a page to an other page on a different domain?
i might need this to embed the content of a cross domain iframe in the page, so it isnt restricted by the same origin policy.
and if this is possible, i dont know why people dont do this instead of sending the height every time to resize the frame for example.

plus, as i wrote in a previous question, youtube probably does this with the comment sections. (on the watch page)
well, thank you for reading this.

Comment: only if the destination domain page implements MessageEvent

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. I don't think there is a specified limit to the length of the message that could be sent.

Sender:
`exampleWindow.postMessage(document.documentElement.innerHTML, *);`

Receiver: 
`window.addEventListener('message', function(e) { /* e.data */ });`

Make sure to specify the targetOrigin other than `*` for security reasons.

Comment: oh.. thank you for the reply.
and then to embed it in the page, i should use appendChild(e.data) for example?

Comment: `appendChild()` expects a node. You could instead do something like `someElement.innerHTML = e.data`.

Comment: so i should do a somevariable = getElementById(someid); and then somevariable.innerHTML = e.data? i dont know much about javascript, but i have to do  this

Comment: Yes, you can try that.